# CakePHP 2 - CakeEmail Proxy Settings

Tags: php, email, cakephp, proxy, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP2 and the default Email Config is as below

```
public $smtp = array(
        'transport'=> 'Smtp',
        'from'      => array('emailaddress'=> 'displayname'),
        'host'     => 'serveraddress',
        'port'     => 25,
        'timeout'  => 30,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client'   => null,
        'log'      => TRUE,
        'delivery'=> 'smtp'
    );
```

However, i would wish to define a proxy server for sending this e-mails.

Can anyone help me defining Proxy Server for sending E-Mails or can i configure a proxy server for all Cake Requests?

Comment: Which email service you want to use?

Comment: My company has its Exchange Server which i would like to use, however, it can only be achieved if i use a proxy server!